# How do I notify the client of success/failure when creating users with no password?

Tags: meteor, user-accounts

I'm building an application that doesn't support public registration. New users will be created by an existing user and an enrollment email will be sent to the new user's email address. I've got this all working, but my implementation feels hackish.

Here's the code, so far.

Template:

```
<template name="addUser">
    <form role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
            <input name="firstName" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
            <input name="lastName" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" />
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">{{faIcon 'plus'}} Add User</button>
    </form>
</template>
```

Template's Javascript:

```
Template.addUser.events({
    'submit form': function (e, t) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var attrs = {
            email: t.find('[name="email"]').value,
            profile: {
                firstName: t.find('[name="firstName"]').value,
                lastName: t.find('[name="lastName"]').value,
            }
        };

        Meteor.call('addUser', attrs, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                Errors.throw(err.reason);
            } else {
                Router.go('home');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

My `addUser` method

```
Meteor.methods({
    addUser: function (attrs) {
        var user = Meteor.user();

        if (!user) throw new Meteor.Error(401, 'Please login.');
        if (!attrs.profile.firstName) throw new Meteor.Error(422, 'Please include a first name.');
        if (!attrs.profile.lastName) throw new Meteor.Error(422, 'Please include a first name.');
        if (!attrs.email) throw new Meteor.Error(422, 'Please include an email.');

        var user = _.pick(attrs, ['firstName', 'lastName', 'email']);

        if (Meteor.isServer) {
            var newUserId = Accounts.createUser(attrs);
            Accounts.sendEnrollmentEmail(newUserId);
        }
    }
});
```

Since `Accounts.createUser` requires a password on the client side, I can't figure out how to notify the client of success or failure short of doing something hacky with `Session`. What's a good way to go about doing such a thing?

Comment: What information exactly you're trying to send to the user? I can see you throwing some `Errors` around. Isn't that enough? BTW, why not put the entire method on server only? Also, remember that the last argument of `Meteor.call` can be a callback which you can use to detect if the method execution was successful.

Comment: I'd like to notify the user if either the `Accounts.createUser` or `Accounts.sendEnrollmentEmail` calls fail. I'd normally look for the error param in the callback, but `Accounts.createUser` throws an exception if you pass it a callback on the server. "Error: Accounts.createUser with callback not supported on the server yet." The best I've come up with since posting the question is adding something to the effect of `if (!newUserId) {
   throw new Meteor.Error(500, 'An error occurred creating the user on the server. Please try again.');
  }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, put `addUser` method on server only (i.e. in `server` dir):

```
Meteor.methods({
  addUser: function (attrs) {
    var user = Meteor.user();

    if (!user) // you can also check this.userId here
        throw new Meteor.Error(401, 'Please login.');

    if (!attrs.profile.firstName)
       throw new Meteor.Error(422, 'Please include a first name.');

    if (!attrs.profile.lastName)
      throw new Meteor.Error(422, 'Please include a first name.');

    if (!attrs.email)
      throw new Meteor.Error(422, 'Please include an email.');

    var user = _.pick(attrs, ['firstName', 'lastName', 'email']);

    var newUserId = Accounts.createUser(attrs);
    Accounts.sendEnrollmentEmail(newUserId);
  }
});
```

Then, on the client, you can do something like:

```
 Meteor.call('addUser', attrs, function (err) {
   if (err) {
     console.log('something went wrong :(');
   }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks. I've since put it in the server folder, and I already had code to handle the error `Meteor.call` callback. I dug into the source for Accounts and `createUser` seems to `throw new Meteor.Error` if it fails. 

Is it safe to assume those errors will be sent down the wire to the `Meteor.call` callback if thrown?

Sadly, `sendEnrollmentEmail` just does `throw new Error` though.

Comment: I guess that's exactly what the `err` argument in the callback is designed for :)

Answer (score -3):

Give the user a default password.

(I recommend using the `check()` function inside your `addUser` method – replacing some of your `if` statements. Also, you don't need `Meteor.isServer` as long as you put the js-file inside the `/server` folder.)

Comment: For security reasons, I don't want default passwords.

Comment: Of course, a global password isn't safe, but you can easily generate safe individual passwords for users to change later. (P.S. Please don't down-vote an answer simply because you don't agree with it – down-voting is for misleading or irrelevant answers. Trying to help here ;))

Comment: I down voted your answer because you gave me a work around instead of a solution to the question I asked.